# Minimizing Rayleigh Quotient With Constraint For Un-symmetric Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, quadratic-forms

Let $M$ be a matrix whose rows add to $0$. $M$ is *not* symmetric. Can we bound the following quantity in any meaningful way?

$$\min_{x : \ x \perp 1} \frac{x^TMx}{x^Tx}.$$

A bound involving properties of $M$ (such as its eigenvalues or other properties) would be interesting.

Comment: $x^T M x = x^T\dfrac{1}{2}(M+M^T)x$ so you can bound it in terms of the eigenvalues of $M+M^T.$

Comment: Let $B$ be a matrix whose columns yield a orthonormal base of the orthogonal space of $1$. Then, the minimum is given by the smallest eigenvalue of $1/2 B^T (M + M^T) B$.